# State array not populating in React

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to do a simple operation to create an array in React and set it equal to a state object. Anyone know why state.countState is being populated with "null" for each array element? I think I'm missing something very simple here...

```
class DisplaySort extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
      countState: [],
    };
    this.sort = this.sort.bind(this);
  }

 render() {
    return (
        <div className="buttons">
          <button onClick={this.sort}>Sort</button>
        </div>
    );
  }

sort(e) {
    let data = this.state.array;
    let arr = [...data];
    let min = Math.min(...arr);
    let max = Math.max(...arr);

    let i = min,
      j = 0,
      len = arr.length,
      count = [];

    for (i; i <= max; i++) {
      count[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      count[arr[i]] += 1;
    }

    this.setState({ countState: count });

};
```

Comment: `Math.min([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])` returns `NaN`.

Comment: What should `sort` do? It doesn't appear to be sorting the array.

Comment: This is a truncated version of my application for simplicity. I've narrowed down the (or at least a) problem down to the fact that this returns an array of "null" for count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.min` and `Math.max` doesn't take an array as a parameter.

You can spread the array and pass the values:

```js
const bla = [1,0,-1];

console.log(Math.min(bla)) // logs NaN

console.log(Math.min(...bla)) // logs -1
```

**Update**

In this `for` loop

```
for (i; i <= max; i++) {
   count[i] = 0;
}
```

you're looping from 1 to 5 and in each iteration `count[i]` is set to 0. So that leaves out the first index(0).
If you log `count` after this loop you'll see that the first element is null.

Comment: Even after adding the spread operator the count array is still populated with "null" elements

Comment: @Jerry123 updated my answer, you have a logical error.